# Running a full node VS mining

Tags: full-node

I read the following on bitcoin.org

> A full node is a program that fully validates transactions and blocks.
> Almost all full nodes also help the network by accepting transactions
> and blocks from other full nodes, validating those transactions and
> blocks, and then relaying them to further full nodes.
>
> Most full nodes also serve lightweight clients by allowing them to
> transmit their transactions to the network and by notifying them when
> a transaction affects their wallet. If not enough nodes perform this
> function, clients won’t be able to connect through the peer-to-peer
> network—they’ll have to use centralized services instead.
>
> Many people and organizations volunteer to run full nodes using spare
> computing and bandwidth resources—but more volunteers are needed to
> allow Bitcoin to continue to grow. This document describes how you can
> help and what helping will cost you.

In some ways it sounds like they are describing mining when they say "validating those transactions and blocks", but I also believe running a full node is different than mining. In what way is running a full node help the bitcoin network? Does it just help transfer information about transactions that have been processed by miners?

If running a full node is in fact distinct from mining, what incentive do people have to run full nodes if they aren't able to earn the reward as a miner would. Is it just for bitcoin supporters who want to help bitcoin grow?

Answer (score 1):

> If running a full node is in fact distinct from mining, what incentive do people have to run full nodes if they aren't able to earn the reward as a miner would. Is it just for bitcoin supporters who want to help bitcoin grow?

Incentives to run and use a bitcoin full node:

1. Not trusting anyone, verifying everything.
2. Privacy. Not sharing information about your transactions with others.
3. Enforce consensus rules.